# Error creating ElasticSearch domain: InvalidTypeException: Invalid instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform, opensearch

I'm trying to launch an OpenSearch domain using Terraform.

Here's my template

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
  domain_name           = "apple-logs"
  elasticsearch_version = "OpenSearch_1.2"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "t3.large.elasticsearch"
    }

tags = {
      Environment   = "prod"
    }
}
```

When I try to apply the template I get this error:

`Error: Error creating ElasticSearch domain: InvalidTypeException: Invalid instance type: t3.large.elasticsearch`

I've tried changing it to `t3.medium.elasticsearch`, same issue.

I've tried changing the verision to `7.10`, same issue.

Please help.

Comment: If you do `"t3.large.search"` instead of `"t3.large.elasticsearch"`?

Comment: I get this error if I do that `Error: Error creating ElasticSearch domain: ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 't3.large.search' at 'elasticsearchClusterConfig.instanceType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [m6i.xlarge.elasticsearch,....etc`

Comment: Ok, and which version of AWS provider are you using? Because if you look at the pricing page, they all have `.search` suffix: https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/pricing/. Also, large is not supported, only medium and small for t3.

Comment: ok it accepted small. But the list above clearly had t3.large for some reason. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us. :) Always happy to help!